# Next: App router login component is not showing server side errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a form created using zod for email and passsword, I want to catch server error for server errors when login but component is rendering again so the api errors are vanishing ..., how to achieve if login success then fine else show api's error.

Note: I want to just show if server is throwing any errors like something went wrong or invalid password just show in p tag

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET ?? "",
    }),
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "email", },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" },

      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        console.log("credentials", credentials);

        const user = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        }).then((res) => res.json());

        // const user = { id: "1", name: "John", email: credentials?.email };
        console.log("user", user.data);

        if (user) {
          // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
          return user.data;
          // set token in session
        } else {
          // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
          return null;

          // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter

        }
      },

    }),
    
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/", //sigIn page,
    signOut: "/",
    error: "/not-found", // Error code page
    verifyRequest: "/",
  },
};
```

This is my form code :

```
  const defaultValues = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };
  const callbackUrl = searchParams.get("callbackUrl");
  const form = useForm<UserFormValue>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data: UserFormValue) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        callbackUrl: callbackUrl ?? "/dashboard",
      });
      console.log("response", response);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Where this `onSubmit` is called?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar on form submit for login and password

Comment: Can you show that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [

    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",

      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "email", },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        console.log("credentials", credentials);

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        }).then((res) => res.json());

        // const user = { id: "1", name: "John", email: credentials?.email };
        console.log("user", response);

        if (response?.status === 200) {
          return { ...response.data, email: credentials?.email };
        } else if (response?.status === 422) {
          throw new Error(response.message);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },

    }),

  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = "Anuj";
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.userRole;
        token.token = user.token;
      }
      return token;

    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any, token: any }) {
      session.id = token.id;
      session.name = "Anuj";
      session.email = token.email;
      session.role = token.role;
      session.token = token.token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/", //sigIn page,
  },
};
```